# Apache mod_proxy rewriting urls to origin server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, mod-proxy

I have a server running an application (web interface to Cisco Unity voicemail). I'm trying to get users away from the server proper by using an Apache box to front it up using mod_proxy, so clients will access that instead.

I had a look using Burpsuite to find out what paths I needed to proxy, and these are all added. The login works, but once the application loads it fails because it's building a url in Javascript (it's highly ajaxy) to make a request using REST, which it then sends back to the server. Mod proxy passes this, BUT the url should contain the origin server's name (actually it's IP) as a couple of values in the GET string. But, it's just picking it up from host headers and putting it in various values. Once this gets back to the origin voicemail server, it throws a 500 as the URL contains the hostname of the proxy server, as that's what the client-side javascript saw. If I manually modify the URL it sends, and post it through the proxy, it will return data.

I've tried using mod_rewrite, and ProxyPassMatch, but I can't make it re-write the URL properly, subsituting the proxy's hostname with the server's own, thus making it return data. Is ProxyPassMatch the right way? I had it half working, but it was seemingly randomly substituting things, so I couldn't work it out, and the documentation alludes to using key substitutions, but gives zero clue how!

Any help most gratefully received.